# apache removing slash from URL with reverse proxy

Tags: web, server, apache2

Every time I type https://www.alltypesofcontent.com/one/phpmyadmin, it redirects me to https://www.alltypesofcontent.com/onephpmyadmin/ What do I do about this to fix it? I am using apache2 reverse proxy.